# Normalizing location data

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Before I ask the question I just want to say that I am a backend engineer and have no experience in data science, but I'm trying to look into the machine learning solution for this problem and any sort of answer that what I'm trying to do is impossible or that I should be looking into something different is appreciated.

I'm working on a project and we currently want to normalize location data.
User has free text input, and we want to try and map that into a row in the predefined table of all the locations in the world, if possible, and get country, state and city.

So we want to map **input** => **{country, state, city}** for example

```
Schwäbisch Gmünd, Baden-Württemberg, Deutschland => Germany, Baden-Württemberg, Schwäbisch Gmünd
United States, Los Angeles => United States, California, Los Angeles
United States => United States, null, null
Tuscany => Italy, Tuscany, null
Wien => Austria, Vienna, Vienna
```

Is this possible to do this with machine learning? If it is what should we be looking into?

Comment: sounds more like regular database search with some edit-distance similarity metric than a use case of ML

Comment: Yes that is what I had in mind in the beginning, but I was wondering if maybe there is a simpler way to do this with ML

Comment: ML is rarely "simpler" and definitely never simpler than basic search